# How to test reactor chain

Tags: java, testing, reactor

I have the following class:

```
public class Library {

    private BookRepo repo;

    public Library(BookRepo repo) {
        repo = repo; 
    }

    public Mono<Void> deleteBook(String title) {
        return repo.deleteBookSubscriptions(title).then(repo.deleteBook(title));
    }

    class BookRepo {
        public Mono<Void> deleteBookSubscriptions(String title) {
            return Mono.empty();
        }

        public Mono<Void> deleteBook(String title) {
            return Mono.empty();
        }
    }

    class Book {}
}
```

and I want to test the method `Library#deleteBook`, that two methods executed in the same pipeline, but not in the different ones. 
With another words they should be executed like this:

```
public Mono<Void> deleteBook(String title) {
    return repo.deleteBookSubscriptions(title).then(repo.deleteBook(title));
}
```

But not like this:

```
public Mono<Void> deleteBook(String title) {
    repo.deleteBookSubscriptions(title);
    return repo.deleteBook(title);
}
```